# Rearrange Table Data using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have data in the following format:

```
(Table: Hours)
{ Date = "21/04/2008", Person = Sally, Hours= 3 }
{ Date = "21/04/2008", Person = Sam, Hours = 15 }
{ Date = "22/04/2008", Person = Sam, Hours = 8 }
{ Date = "22/04/2008", Person = Sally, Hours = 9 }
```

Datatypes: Date = Date, Person = String, Hours = Integer

Using LINQ I would like to select it into this format:

```
{ Date = "21/04/2008", Sam = 15, Sally = 3 }
{ Date = "22/04/2008", Sam = 8, Sally = 9 }
```

Datatypes: Date = Date, Sam = Integer, Sally = Integer

Is this possible?

Comment: If number of persons is more than two, then?

Comment: @X-TECH I assume it would be like { Date="...", Person1 = .., Person2 = .., Person3 = .....}

Comment: What exactly is the type of  `Person`? Is it a class or?

Comment: @CliveDM `Person` is `Column` in `Hours` table

Comment: @X-TECH As for the `table`, is it a `DataTable`, `string literal`, data that you get from a database or some other type that I don't know of?

Comment: @CliveDM you are correct with  { Date="...", Person1 = .., Person2 = .., Person3 = .....}.  Its data I will retrieve from a sql database.

Comment: @X-TECH What I assumed is that each entry is a class which have three properties `Date`:string, `Person`:_i-don't-know-of_, `Hours`:int.

Comment: @CliveDM sorry, person is a string.

Comment: @Reafidy I don't think you can put `15` into `Sam` which is a string

Comment: @CliveDM In the first Table the Person column is a string, Hours is an integer. In the second results table, Sam is Integer and Sally is an integer.

Comment: @Reafidy Do you want LINQ only?

Comment: @Reafidy Yep, if you want it to be returned as C# type, you can use AD.Net 's answer, dotctor 's answer would work well for serializing to Json.

Comment: If you down-vote, could you please let me know where I went wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from d in data
group d by d.Date into g
select new {Date = g.Key, People = g.Select(gg=>new{Person = gg.Person, Hours = gg.Hours})}
```

This will give you the data, then it's just formatting to display properly.

Comment: This seems to give me:    [{"Date":"21/04/2008","People":[{"Person":"Sally","Hours":3},{"Person":"Sam","Hours":15}]},{"Date":"22/04/2008","People":[{"Person":"Sally","Hours":8},{"Person":"Sam","Hours":9}]}]

Comment: I really need: [{ Date = "21/04/2008", Sam = 15, Sally = 3 },{ Date = "22/04/2008", Sam = 8, Sally = 9 }]

Comment: @Reafidy I don't think it's easy to create different type with different properties whose name you don't even know at the coding time. Try google for `dynamic` keyword in c# or do it using reflection.

Comment: @Reafidy, the data regarding the person and hours is just that, DATA. These are not properties, you can create that output in a string format without much difficulty but I think you're confused with the data and string formatting for output

Comment: I am serializing the result to Json and parsing it to a webpage which has a graph and requires it in the format above.  It wont recognize the fields correctly in that format your solution gives me and I cant seem to convert it.

Comment: @CliveDM, I'm not sure I follow.  The datatype doesn't need to be dynamic it will always be Integer for the hours.  I am just wanting a dynamic amount of people with their hours for each day.

Comment: @Reafidy Yes, the data type for `Sam` and `Sally` are always `int`s, but what about the entire entry? `{ Date = "21/04/2008", Sam = 15, Sally = 3 }` means that you have an entry of a type that have: ** `Date`: string, `Sam`: int, `Sally`: int. **

Comment: @CliveDB There is no datatype for the entire entry they are all separate field's just as though they were in a datatable.  The primary key would be the date column.

Comment: @Reafidy You `can` do such thing. Check out my answer.

Comment: @AD.Net As in my answer, you can create the **exact** bunch of types Reafidy wants, but I don't see any necessity though.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you have a table that log the amount of hours each employee has worked in specific data. I assume it can contains multiple logs from a person in a day. If you don't want to use LINQ you can use this

```
var hours = new[] {
                        new { Date = "21/04/2008", Person = "Sally", Hours= 3 },
                        new { Date = "21/04/2008", Person = "Sam", Hours = 15 },
                        new { Date = "22/04/2008", Person = "Sam", Hours = 8 },
                        new { Date = "22/04/2008", Person = "Sally", Hours = 9 },
                        new { Date = "22/04/2008", Person = "John", Hours = 5 },
                        new { Date = "22/04/2008", Person = "John", Hours = 2 },
                        new { Date = "22/04/2008", Person = "Tom", Hours = 9 },
                   };


var result = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
foreach (var workLog in hours)
{
    if (!result.ContainsKey(workLog.Date))
        result[workLog.Date] = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    if (!result[workLog.Date].ContainsKey(workLog.Person))
        result[workLog.Date][workLog.Person] = 0;

    result[workLog.Date][workLog.Person] += workLog.Hours;
}

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
```

and result is

> {"21/04/2008":{"Sally":3,"Sam":15},"22/04/2008":{"Sam":8,"Sally":9,"John":7,"Tom
>   ":9}}

Comment: Can this be changed to this format: [{ Date:21/04/2008, Sam:15, Sally:3},{Date:22/04/2008, Sam:8,Sally:9,John:7,Tom:9} ]

Answer (score 2):

Update:

If you want it to just be string literal.

```
string.Concat("[", 
              string.Concat(data.GroupBy(d=>d.Date) .Select(d=>
               {
                   var str = string.Format("{{ Date = \"{0}\", ", d.Key);
                   var ds = d.Select(p=>string.Format("{0} = {1}, ", p.Person, p.Hours)).ToArray();
                   return string.Concat(str, string.Concat(ds), " },");
               })),
              "]");
```

---

If you *want it to be a bunch of `objects` with such structure*:

Here's the solution:

```
class Program
{
    public class Data
    {
        public string Date;
        public string Person;
        public int Hours;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new Data[]
        {
            new Data { Date = "21/04/2008", Person = "Sally", Hours= 3 },
            new Data { Date = "21/04/2008", Person = "Sam", Hours = 15 },
            new Data { Date = "22/04/2008", Person = "Sam", Hours = 8 },
            new Data { Date = "22/04/2008", Person = "Sally", Hours = 9 },
        };

        var aName = new AssemblyName("DynamicModule");
        var mb = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
            .DefineDynamicAssembly(aName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave)
            .DefineDynamicModule(aName.Name, aName.Name + ".dll");

        var list = new List<object>();
        foreach (var d in data.GroupBy(d=>d.Date))
        {
            var t = mb.DefineType("T" + d.Key);
            t.DefineField("Date", typeof(string), FieldAttributes.Public);
            foreach (var p in d)
            {
                t.DefineField(p.Person, typeof(int), FieldAttributes.Public);
            }
            var type = t.CreateType();

            object e = Activator.CreateInstance(type, 
                          BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, null, null);
            t.GetDeclaredField("Date").SetValue(e, d.Key);
            d.ToList().ForEach(dd=>t.GetDeclaredField(dd.Person).SetValue(e, dd.Hours));

            list.Add(e);
        }

        foreach (var e in list)
        {
            Console.Write("{ ");
            foreach (var f in e.GetType().GetFields().OrderBy(f=>f.Name))
            {
                Console.Write(string.Format(" {0} = {1} ", f.Name, f.GetValue(e)));
            }
            Console.Write(" }\n");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Prints out:

```
{  Date = 21/04/2008  Sally = 3  Sam = 15  }
{  Date = 22/04/2008  Sally = 9  Sam = 8   }
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm well and truly confused now.  Your code is far beyond my knowledge and it looks impressive.  I'm not concerned with datatypes and I'm failing to see why there important,  I just want a string output like this: `[{ Date = "21/04/2008", Sam = 15, Sally = 3 },{ Date = "22/04/2008", Sam = 8, Sally = 9 }]` because that's what the telerik graph on my webpage accepts in json format.

Comment: @Reafidy I just realize that all you want is to get a string literal like this. That's pretty simple. See my update.

Comment: Good stuff, that's the result I'm after but one small problem it prints the \ slash `"[{ Date = \"21/04/2008 12:00:00 AM\", Sally = 3, Sam = 15,  }{ Date = \"22/04/2008 12:00:00 AM\", Sally = 8, Sam = 9,  }]"`

Comment: @Reafidy Well, it doesn't on my machine `[{ Date = "21/04/2008", Sally = 3, Sam = 15,  },{ Date = "22/04/2008", Sam = 8, Sally = 9,  },]`, And it shouldn't be.

Comment: Your completely right, although I was using your exact code, I was unaware I was serializing the code in the printout twice.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Reafidy Glad to help.